# Godot C# "Error calling method from signal"

Tags: c#, signals, godot

Given my scene tree:

`Main_control` (Type:Control) (Parent)

- `mnk_game` (Type: Control) (Child)

I can run methods in `mnk_game`'s script using signals from `Main_control`, but it won’t work the other way around (calling a method in `Main_control` using a signal from `mnk_game`)

Error:

> emit_signal: Error calling method from signal 'mnk_game_finished': 'Control(Main_control.cs)::mnk_show_game': Method not found..

Parent's code:

```css
public class Main_control : Control
{
  public override void _Ready()
  {pass}
  public void mnk_show_game()
  {
    GD.Print("mnk_show_game reached"); //What I want to reach
  }
}
```

Child code:

```css
public class mnk_game : Control
{
  [Signal]
  public delegate void mnk_game_finished();
  private Godot.Control game_controller;

  public override void _Ready()
  {
    game_controller = (Control)GetParent<Godot.Control>();
    this.Connect("mnk_game_finished", game_controller, "mnk_show_game");
  }
  public void any_method()
  {
    this.EmitSignal("mnk_game_finished");
  }
}
```

When I call the `any_method` method at the child's script, I want to be able to reach `mnk_show_game` method in the parent's script. Can I do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience using Godot with C#, but I can see that `mnk_game_finished` was defined without parameters and `mnk_show_game` also does not take parameters. However, you are emitting the signal with a parameter `this.EmitSignal("mnk_game_finished", ds.board)`. Try to emit the signal without a parameter like so: `this.EmitSignal("mnk_game_finished")` or define your delegate and function with parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I mistakenly kept that variable in the post. Trying to make my code run, I removed any arguments from the function, but still not working. I just edited my question with your feedback :)